# Javascript help - slowing page down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api

I'm not experienced in Javascript, so apologies if this is a basic question, but I have a js script in the head of my application that is slowing down the page loading time (e.g. examplepage.php). The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $("a").click(function(){

    $.get('getdata.php', function(data) {
            $('#getdata').html(data);
        });
  });

});
</script>
```

getdata.php runs a script that connects to another service via an API. On examplepage.php I have a link that once clicked activates the js script above which pulls in data from the API (via getdata.php). This feature works, but what I am finding is that on loading the page the js script runs anyway and therefore slows down the loading time of the page.

I don't want the script to be calling the API unnecessarily (ie. if the user doesn't click the link on examplepage.php). How can I stop this js script running?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense - I'm a JS beginner!

Many thanks,

Gregor

Comment: That looks fine to me... the `get` won't be executed unless an element matching the selector is clicked.

Comment: If the user doesn't click the link, the API won't be called. Just feel comfortable.

Comment: Yeh but if I remove the script the application runs fast. If I then add the script it takes a while to load each page (where the script is in the head). So I'm not sure why that is?!

Comment: is this ALL the code you have in this script? If you empty the external function (ie. `$(document).ready(function(){});` ) is the slowdown still in place?

Comment: how many anchor elements are in your page? I am not sure but the event binding may slow down your page load during initialization if there are many anchor elements.

Comment: judging by the handler code there should be just an anchor. Maybe the DOM itself is quite large, a different select expression may help a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you use is semantically equivalent to this one (I've just assigned a name to the anonymous function you use for sake of clarity):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readyAction() {
    $("a").click(clickEvent);
}

function clickEvent() {
    $.get('getdata.php', function(data) {
            $('#getdata').html(data);
        }
}

$(document).ready(readyAction);
</script>
```

You can read it in this way:

`$(document).ready(readyAction);` means when the `$('document')` is full loaded `ready` (it is a simplification) then execute the function `readyAction`. Note that the function is addressed (there aren't the () after his name) and not executed at this line.

The readyAction function does just a thing: scan the DOM and find all the anchors `$("a")`
and then hook to the collected elements an handler `clickEvent` for the onclick event.

The function `clickEvent` do the XHR connection, retrieve the data from server and then fill the `div` (or whatever the element is) with id getdata. It will be executed only when the user clicks on a link.

That's all.

You are not issuing extra unneeded XHR calls with this code.
I hope this had shed some light on the inner workings of that code.

**EDIT**
As pointed by Quincy, maybe the DOM you want to manipulate is quite large, or there are a lot of anchor elements and this may slow down your execution, it is a rare chance but maybe it is your case. You can try to restrict the scope of search done by jquery adding an id to the link you want to *animate*.

i.e. you can change `$("a").click(` in `$("#loadpagedatalink').click(` as far 'loadpagedatalink' is the id of the link you have to attach the click handler to.

Comment: That worked taking away the "a" and replacing with an id. Thanks.